# How long must I stay outside of Russia before entering again with an e-visa?

Tags: visas, russia, 90-180-visa-rules, repeat-visits, e-visas

During my visit in Russia, I’ve spent all the 16 days of the e-visa, I want to visit Russia again soon. Do I have to stay 16 days outside of Russia before entering again with a new e-visa? Or is it irrelevant?

Comment: I suggest trying to apply for a new e-visa, since the old one is no longer valid (it's single entry). If they grant it to you, then I bet you can enter during the validity period. If not, you will answer your own question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official sources (https://evisa.kdmid.ru/) don't mention any mandatory time spent outside Russia before one becomes eligible for a new e-visa.

Your best option would be to simply apply for a new e-visa. If it gets approved, perfect; if not, you'll have to wait. Don't make any travel plans until it's approved.

Alternately, you can also contact a Russian consulate with this question, but I'm afraid you won't learn anything more than *"each visa application is evaluated individually, on a case-by-case basis, etc."*. If there was a fixed rule it the law, it would have been published on the websites. Since it's not published, there's probably no fixed rule.

Comment: Or you can pay one of the many sort-of-corrupt visa businesses that deal with Russian visas.

Comment: @Simd That would cost a lot more money than an e-visa, would require a lot more paperwork, and would have the same uncertain outcome.

Comment: You may be right about the lack of certainty.